# Cloning Terraform GitHub module inside private org - permission denied

Tags: terraform, github-actions

I have the following module that we are trying to clone via SSH (NOTE: we prefer to not use https) in Terraform:

```
module "example-module" {
  source = "git@github.com:private-org/example-module.git?ref=v1.0.0"
}
```

However, we have a GitHub actions runner that fails when trying to do a `terraform init` on this module:

> Permission denied (publickey). Could not read Password for
> 'https://***@github.com': No such device or address

So to give this permission, we are trying to add inside `.gitconfig`:

```
[url "https://{GITHUB_TOKEN}@github.com"]
    insteadOf = "ssh://git@github.com"
```

And inside the GitHub actions we are trying to replace `GITHUB_TOKEN` with the actual value:

```
- name: Configure SSH
  run: |
    sed -i 's/{GITHUB_TOKEN}/${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}/g' .gitconfig
    cat .gitconfig >> ~/.gitconfig
```

But we are still getting the same error. Any ideas for how we can authenticate to a private module inside our GitHub org and successfully clone via SSH?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out the answer. The default `GITHUB_TOKEN` did not have have the right access rights and was not deemed a "Personal Access Token". This seems a little confusing on GitHub's part and the reason it was getting the error `Could not read Password`

You will need to generate a new personal access token in GitHub, and add that as a GitHub Actions secret called `NEW_GITHUB_TOKEN`. Add read:repo and write:repo as access rights and set the token to never expire.

Your `.gitconfig` should look like:

```
[url "https://{GITHUB_TOKEN}@github.com"]
    insteadOf = "ssh://git@github.com"
```

And a step in your GitHub Actions that uses your new personal access token:

```
- name: Configure SSH
  run: |
    sed -i 's/{GITHUB_TOKEN}/${{ secrets.NEW_GITHUB_TOKEN }}/g' .gitconfig
    cat .gitconfig >> ~/.gitconfig
```

Comment: this solution about the `.gitconfig` helped a lot, you did save me with this one, but I would like to explain some things about the `GITHUB_TOKEN`, by default it doesn't have the correct permissions to do many things, but you can control this at the job level with the `permissions` list, meaning that at run time it will create the `GITHUB_TOKEN` with more permissions than the default, so you don't need to create a PAT just for this, you can find more about it here, use `repository-projects: read` https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#permissions